# I need to tell an Activity to refresh data, from a Service. Is there any reason to use a bound service or intent, instead of a singleton?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I don't need to pass any data, just tell it to refresh. I'm currently doing something like:

```
Activity a = MyActivity.getSingleton();
if (a != null) {
    a.refreshUI();
}
```

Is this OK, or do I need to use a bound service, intent, etc. for some reason?

Comment: You cannot do it that way on android, use service to load data store the data in a content provider and register to a contact observer in the activity to get notified about data changes

Comment: If components don't need to know about each other (which is a good thing), use `LocalBroadcastManager` or even better something like [greenrobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [square Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), those are a bit simpler to use. Telling your activity to update that way is btw totally not [Hollywood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle)

Comment: EventBus is extremely easy to use. I have been so happy that I've integrated it to my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking I believe your example code could work. However, it would be difficult, if possible, to implement correctly because the creation and updating of MyActivity's singleton member would be non-standard, since the OS creates and destroys activities as it pleases, and won't call your getSingleton() method.

Also this goes against Android conventions. The Android convention for communicating from a Service to  an Activity within the same application is to send and receive local broadcasts using the LocalBroadcastManager. A scenario similar to your own is described on the Android developer's site:
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html.

Using broadcasts is preferable because it can make your Service more reusable. The Service doesn't have to be aware of what other components are listening to its broadcasts and how to call into them. And your Activity doesn't have to maintain a specific interface for the Service to call.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a broadcast for that, the problem is that with a singleton you will never know if the activity is still alive or not or in what state it is, rather using a broadcast if the activity is dead it will be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's exactly what you want:

[refresh activity from service after notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205813/refresh-activity-from-service-after-notification/25206048#25206048)

PS do not use singleton for this purposes cause it can be issue of memory leak.